# A subgroup of order $12$ for $SL(2, 3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $G$ be $SL(2, 3)$, the group of $2×2$ matrices with determinant $1$ and with entries in $\mathbb{Z/3Z}$.

Assume that $H$ is a subgroup of order $12$ in $SL(2, 3)$. Argue that $H$
must contain an element of order $2$, all eight elements of order $3$, and
eight elements of order $6$, and hence $H$ cannot exist.

---

Answer:

I am trying to show that the existence of element $A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is neccseray in $H$, but I have no clues yet. Also, The product of this element with any element of order $3$ is an element of order $6$.
If we can prove that $A$ and all eight elements of order $3$ are necessary, we will finish the proof.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), $H$ contains an element of order $2$ and an element of order $3$.

The cardinality of $SL_2(\mathbf{F}_3)$ is $24$, so the index of $H$ is $2$. In other words, for each element of $SL_2(\mathbf{F}_3)$, either it is in $H$ or its square is.

Can you now show that this forces all order $3$ elements of $SL_2(\mathbf{F}_3)$ to be in $H$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, It's clear now for me.